# Jquery not working with IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I did this jquery to basically check on a php page and turn whatever the result is. It is working fine in other browsers but unfortunately I am having issues with IE. The bad news for this is that most of the users will be using IE.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#value').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'../validation.php',
            data: {
                validate_year:$('#Year').val(),
                validate_value:$('#value').val(),
                validate_domain:$('#Domain').val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#status').empty().append(data).addClass('red_validate');
            }
        })
    });
});
```

how can I making this work on IE. Thanks

Comment: Please provide details of exactly how it is not working in IE. Does it throw an exception / display an error message etc?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using and what IE versions are broken?

Comment: IE doesn't like trailing commas in object literals, so take the comma off of the end of `validate_domain:$('#Domain').val(),`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the trailing comma from the last item in your `data` object:

```
data: {
    validate_year:$('#Year').val(),
    validate_value:$('#value').val(),
    validate_domain:$('#Domain').val() // <--- Should NOT have a comma
},
```